# ConfigParser no "lanza" excepciones como es de esperar

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Cada vez que ejecuto la función "**escribir_archivo_de_configuracion**" esta añade una nueva sección **repetida**, con el mismo nombre, a pesar de que "**add_section**" debe lanzar una excepción "**DuplicateSectionError**" cuando se intenta crear una sección ya existente...

```
    import configparser

    archivo_configuracion = 'config.ini'

    def escribir_archivo_de_configuracion(seccion, nombre_dato, dato):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        try:
            config.add_section(seccion)

        except configparser.DuplicateSectionError:
            config.set(seccion,nombre_dato,dato)

        with open(archivo_configuracion, 'a') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)

    
    escribir_archivo_de_configuracion('memoria', 'memoria5', 'Prueba memoria5')
```

Y, por supuesto, no escribe la opción correspondiente, que debería ser algo así:

```
    [memoria]
        memoria5 = Prueba memoria5
```

Archivo '**Config.ini**'

```
    [memoria]
        

    [memoria]
        

    [memoria]
```

**Estoy usando Python 3.10 con PyCharm en Windows 10.**

Por cierto, también he probado por mapeo, pero nada...
En fin, imagino que será algún error clamoroso por mi parte, pero no se me ocurre cuál.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios temas a revisar en tu código, veamos:

1. El objecto `config` se inicializa en blanco al comienzo de `escribir_archivo_de_configuracion`, por lo cual, puedes repetir ejecuciones pero la sección siempre será nueva, es decir nunca tendrás una excepción por sección duplicada. Entiendo que deberías en la primera instancia incializar `config` leyendo el archivo `config.ini`
2. El `config.set()` solo se ejecuta si hubo una excepción y ya vimos que esta jamás ocurre. Es rara esta lógica, si resolvemos el primer punto, de todas formas, el `config.set()` solo se ejecutará cuando la sección ya exista, lo más natural sería crear la sección y luego llamar directamente al `config.set()`
3. Estas salvando el objeto `config` haciendo un `append` con lo cual siempre agregará la sección al archivo

Te sugiero algunos cambios:

```
import configparser

archivo_configuracion = 'config.ini'

def escribir_archivo_de_configuracion(seccion, nombre_dato, dato):

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    # Procesamos el INI
    config.read(archivo_configuracion)

    try:
        config.add_section(seccion)
    except configparser.DuplicateSectionError:
      # Si existe la sección no hacemos nada
      pass
    
    # Seteamos el dato
    config.set(seccion,nombre_dato,dato)
   
    with open(archivo_configuracion, 'w') as configfile:
      config.write(configfile)


escribir_archivo_de_configuracion('memoria', 'memoria5', 'Prueba memoria5')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio, he añadido la línea que me indicaste: `config.read(archivo_configuracion)` y ahora funciona como es de esperar...